# Sum of n + n(n-1) + n(n-1)(n-2) + ... + n!

Tags: sequences-and-series, summation, factorial, recursion

This is to work out the time complexity of a computer science problem (write an algorithm to calculate the permutations of an array of n distinct integers).

Various answers on leetcode say the sum tends towards n*n! , but none of the proofs seem very well explained, so reaching out to the maths overlords.

Comment: Add $1$ and factor out $n!$ from every term.  Rearrange the sum from back-to-front.  You have the sum is $n!(\frac{1}{1!}+\frac{1}{2!}+\frac{1}{3!}+\frac{1}{4!}+\frac{1}{5!}+\dots+\frac{1}{n!})$  This sum inside the parentheses you should recognize as being related to $e$.

Comment: Thanks @JMoravitz exactly what I was looking for! If you add this as an answer I can select it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

@JMoravitz answered the question in the comments section:

> Add 1 and factor out ! from every term. Rearrange the sum from back-to-front. You have the sum is $!(\frac{1}{1!}+\frac{1}{2!}+\frac{1}{3!}+\frac{1}{4!}+\frac{1}{5!}+ ⋯ +\frac{1}{!})$ This sum inside the parentheses you should recognize as being related to .